# How to call a method in controller from console application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, console-application

I have tried to call a method in controller (mvc) from console application.It has integer value as parameter.How to pass the integer value from console application to controller as parameter.How to run this and check.

Method call from console application:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {


        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:60035/AddDataToDataBaseController/AddData");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();


    }
}
```

}

controller method:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AddData(int fileDetailsId)
    {
        var response = new ResponseDTO();
        FileDetails fileDetails = _addingDataDl.GetFileDetails(fileDetailsId);
        bool hasKnowParts = false;
        FileProcess fileProcess = _addingDataDl.GetFileProcess(fileDetailsId, Enumerations.ProcessType.Parsed);
        try
        {
            Entities.User user = _userRepository.GetUserByUserName(User.Identity.Name);
            if (fileDetails != null)
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code? The problem is likely that you are using the URL `AddDataToDataBaseController/AddData` when it should be `AddDataToDataBase/AddData` though

Comment: var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:60035/AddDataToDataBase/AddData"); changed it ,I have doubt in how to pass parameter ,when it is integer type and get the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There look two problems with this:

One is the name of controller in URL. It should be `AddDataToDataBase` instead.

Second is missing integer parameter. Add the parameter in request. Try following code.

```
byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("fileDetailsId=1");//Prepare data to write to write to request
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:60035/AddDataToDataBase/AddData");
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
httpWebRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;//Here you set the content length
Stream stream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();
stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);//Here you write your parameters to the request
var response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the parameter into your POST data. This is done by writing to the RequestStream of the WebRequest. Like so:

```
var filedetails = "filedetails=1";
var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(filedetails);
var requestStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
requestStream.Close();
```

You'll also have to change the content type to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".